# How to list rows individually when using in controller not view

Tags: php, codeigniter

On the view if i post like this it works, but i want each column individually in this controller. i can do this on first foreach but on second one i want how to do that when i am using `$field_name` - what code do i need to add to this?

```
    <?php foreach($formates as $formate): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($fields as $field_name => $field_display): ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo $formate->$field_name(HERE i want individualy ?>
        </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

controller

```
$data['fields'] = array(
    'FID' => 'ID',
    'title' => 'Title',
    'category' => 'Category',
    'dep_id' => 'Department',
    'bf_linkpdf' => 'pdf',
    'bf_linkxls' => 'xls',
    'bf_linkdoc' => 'doc'
);
```

on the view i want to list them indevidualy

```
    <?php foreach($formates as $formate): ?>
<tr>
    <?php foreach($fields as $field_name => $field_display): ?>
    <td>
        <?php echo $formate->$field_name->FID ?>
            <?php echo $formate->$field_name->title ?>
            <?php echo $formate->$field_name->category ?>
            <?php echo $formate->$field_name->dep_id ?>
    </td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

regards
thanks in advance.

Comment: if some one help, plz

Comment: can you show one example like what is the array you are getting in controller and in which way you want to show in view file......

Comment: Venkat > i the array is on my controller as i shown but if i use
...........<?php echo $formate->$field_name ?> 
this show my full column names and content
but i want to show some of them even i have mention them on controller array but i dont' want to use them in view it mean
<?php echo $formate->$field_name(here what i should rit to get individualy....is it posible ?>

it mean some of columns not all column on array because some my column i want to have link so each has diffrent address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the view I added the following and it started working.

```
           <?php foreach($formates as $formate): ?>
        <tr>
                <td><?php echo $formate->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $formate->title; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $formate->category; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $formate->dep_id; ?></td>
        </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why are you using the first loop `formats` , since your array is field..you can just do

```
<?php foreach($fields as $field): ?>
<td>
    <?php echo $field['FID'] ?>
        <?php echo $field['title'] ?>
        <?php echo $field['category'] ?>
        <?php echo $field['dep_id'] ?>
</td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

OR

each fields name and display in each `<tr>`

```
<?php foreach($fields as $field_name => $field_display): ?>
<tr>
 <td>
    <?php echo $field_name ?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $field_display ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: bipen> your answer is right it works but it shows all column
 here i want separately so i could fix a diffrent links to my each column, if i give a link here so the link for all column will be same

Comment: hear i wand 

like fied_name(1) and feild_display(1)
     feild_name(2) and feild_display(2)

so i could give them diffrent link